# Node.js + Cheerio scraping div id

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I would like to scraping the item-id string, but failed to get item-id="s4b9di" string

this is my code

[image]

what is wrong?

Html page:
[image]

I find the solution:

```
$('.feeditem').each((i, element) => {
    const itemId = $(element).find('[item-id]').attr('item-id');
    console.log(itemId);
});
```

Comment: Can you share where does the cheerio start please...

Comment: edit to full code

Answer (score 2):

Try with this :

```
$('.feeditem').each((i, element) => {
    const itemId = $(this).find('[item-id]').attr('itemId')
});
```

or

```
$('[item-id]').each((i, element) => {
    const itemId = $(this).attr('itemId')
});
```